# Error while inserting data in database

Tags: sql, sql-insert

SQL:

```
insert into student (firstName,email,password) value ('mayank','dave123@gmail.com','1234')
```

Error:

> ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Comment: you missed the `values` keyword instead you are typing `value`

Answer (score 1):

Should it be this instead?  You didn't mention which DB you're using but it's looking for the VALUES keyword.

```
String insertQuery = "insert into student (firstName,email,password) values ('" + firstName + "','" + email+ "','" + password + "')";
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle database 11g EE.Error solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the letter (S) in the word values, so the statement will be

```
insert into student (firstName,email,password) 
 Values
('mayank','dave123@gmail.com','1234')
```